# How to rename/move a file on a remote windows host with ansible?

Tags: ansible

There seem to be several solutions which all act in multiple steps e.g. 
* copy and delete 
* use a native wincommand or pwoershell

But isn't there just a rename as win_module? Or an option on copy to delete the source after a copy?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found some answers to the question:

First it is to point out that this is for a remote windows host. For Unix systems we have a bunch of answers already in stackoverflow, not so for windows.

There is no win_rename module nor a win_file with the option to rename. You can not use win_copy since the file is already on the remote system. So the simplest way is to use a local windows command.

```
- name: rename the {{ source_name }} to  {{ target_name }}
  win_command: "cmd.exe /c rename {{ destination_folder }}\\{{ source_name }} {{ target_name }}"
```

Comment: with the remote_src it's possible to work directly on the remote system

Comment: Error: `fatal: [10.227.26.97]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "cmd.exe rename /c H:\\dir\\nginx-1.23.1 H:\\dir\\nginx81", "delta": "0:00:00.078204", "end": "2022-08-01 04:24:01.226329", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2022-08-01 04:24:01.148125", "stderr": "'H:\\dir\\nginx-1.23.1' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n", "stderr_lines": ["'H:\\dir\\nginx-1.23.1' is not recognized as an internal or external command,", "operable program or batch file."], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}`

Answer (score 0):

MBushveld, I see that your windows "rename" command does the trick nicely in this case.  But in general Powershell commands cover a broader range of circumstances and have more switch/flag options for unique cases.  For example check out the Powershell "Rename-Item" command [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item?view=powershell-5.1).  So if your Windows command comes up short next time you can write a short Powershell script and call it from Ansible with whatever command line arguments you need.  At the bottom of this post is a powershell script I wrote to verify that the contents of 2 text files were exactly the same.  I used the "script:" command in Ansible to call the script with arguments as follows.

```
- name: verify the file contents match
  script: filesAreSame.ps1  "C:/Temp/" "file1.txt" "file2.txt" 
  register: result
- set_fact: filesMatch="{{result.stdout_lines.4 | bool}}"
```

Ansible will move the script to the remote host, execute it and then delete it.  If needed you can use the "register:" command in Ansible as I did to capture any values returned by the script.  Here are the contents of the "filesAreSame.ps1" Powershell script.

```
# verifys that the specified files contain the same text
param(
    [string]$uncPath,
    [string]$uncFile1,
    [string]$uncFile2
)
$uncFullFileName1 = $uncPath + $uncFile1
$uncFullFileName2 = $uncPath + $uncFile2
$filetext1=[System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($uncFullFileName1).TrimStart().TrimEnd()
$filetext2=[System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($uncFullFileName2).TrimStart().TrimEnd()
# verify first file is not empty
if ($filetext1 -eq "")
{
    return "ERROR: Source file is empty"
}
# case sensitive comparison
if ($filetext1 -cne $filetext2)
{
    return "ERROR: Files are not the same"
}
return $TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Old post but it can be useful for future readers.

You could use win_robocopy module, which provides options such as /MOVE for directories and /MOV for files. Robocopy is installed by default on windows machines for years

[Ansible Robocopy module documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/windows/win_robocopy_module.html)
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/windows/win_robocopy_module.html

[Nice feature run-through of robocopy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0q3rGK_IMZg)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `win_shell` module and `Rename-Item` powershell command to achieve it. And we can use `Force` option to handle in case if file is in use etc as well!.

```
  win_shell:
    Rename-Item -Path "C:\Path\To\file\foo.bar" -NewName "foo_new.bar" -Force
```